# How to get value from a combobox item?

Tags: applescript-objc

I would like to take the value selected by the user and add it to a button action.

For example: if you choose "Apple" and click on the open button it will open the Apple website.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this, below what I did.

```
property myComboBox : missing value


on btnOpen:sender
        set theValue to (myComboBox's objectValueOfSelectedItem()) as strings
       if theValue is equal "Apple" then
            open location "https://www.apple.com"
            end if
    end btnOpen:
```

Comment: Note that `sender's objectValueOfSelectedItem()` will be `missing value` if an item is not selected from the menu - for example, text is entered into the combobox (unless it is in the menu list and auto-completion is being used).  If you don’t want the user to enter text, an NSPopUpButton might be better.